# Need to add minSize to fitText

Tags: javascript, jquery, fittextjs

I have fitText working as expected in a jsfiddle but when I copy/paste the code to a web page, an error occurs.

In the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/219us4xs/1/)
click "Design Options", "Customised" and type in any of the 3 inputs. The inputs are restricted to 22 characters and fitText shrinks it accordingly (although not effectively when a customised image is chosen and a secondary "bottom text" is revealed).

```
function update() {
    var size = parseInt($j('#maxsize').val(), 10);

    if (!isNaN(size)) {
        $j('.227').html($j('#input_217').val());
        $j('.296').html($j('#input_294').val());
        $j('.297').html($j('#input_295').val());
        $j('.298').html($j('#input_295').val());
        $j('.jtextfill').textfill({
            maxFontPixels: size
        });
    }
}

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#maxsize').keyup(update);
    $j('#input_217').keyup(update);
    $j('#input_294').keyup(update);
    $j('#input_295').keyup(update);
    update()
});
```

In the [web page demo](http://middlefingerclothing.co.uk/blank/)
click "Design Options", "Customised" and type in any of the 3 inputs (as above). The inputs are restricted to 22 characters and fitText shrinks it accordingly **UNLESS** you keep typing... The 22 character restriction wont show your extra text (good), but each keypress resizes the text smaller and smaller until it reaches 10px (bad). Is this because of the 10 in `var size = parseInt($j('#maxsize').val(), 10);`? I have tried changing this to 26 but not working. The default font-size is 36px and I would like the min text size to be 26px on the we page (as it is on the jsfiddle)

Any help with this issue would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So with a bit of tinkering I figured it out myself...
To add a minimum text size and max font size

```
    if (!isNaN(size)) {
$j('.jtextfill').textfill({
maxFontPixels: 38,
minFontPixels: 24
        });
    }
}
```